# WordPress Added/Enable Thumbnail feature but does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating a wordpress template and I have added thumbnail A.K.A featured image support to my theme just like how the WordPress codex has stated to do it.

Below is the code for enabling support:

```
function cleanslate_setup_theme_support() {

    // Support for post thumbnails a.k.a featured images
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}
```

and

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cleanslate_setup_theme_support' );
```

The code above works I see the option to "Set Featured Image" but upon selecting my image I want to set, it does nothing. I then switched my theme over to a default theme to see if it was my WP Core, and I set featured image and it worked. What might be the problem that my theme could be encountering? Why won't it set or remove image from featured image/thumbnail?

This is how I am using the featured image:

```
<?php  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  ?><header id="imageBanner" class="major-banner major main-wrap wp-bg-image" style="<?php  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' ); echo 'background-image: url(' . $image['0'] . '); ' . ''  ?>"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

When I click "Remove featured image" or "set featured image" I get this in my web browsers console `admin-ajax.php 403 (Forbidden)` on MS Edge `The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. (XHR) Post`

I'm really stuck any ideas would be great wrong or right.

Comment: are you using <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> in your single.php or page.php of your theme ?

Comment: @isuruAbey Yes I have added it, when I switched it to the default theme to set the image then go back to my custom theme the featured images shows in the page. but then when I try to set or remove with my theme it will not get rid of the images there or the image that I selected.

Comment: @isuruAbey I added the code of were I use the featured image

Comment: how you show the content of the page/Post ? can you update the question

Comment: @isuruAbey I did its should be the last piece of code in the question